# substituting ammeter shunts

Tags: power, shunt

I will be connecting a 30A analog DC ammeter in a project soon.  It comes with an external 75mV shunt.  See [http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00A4TQY02](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A4TQY02) for details.

A reviewer stated the shunt was more flimsy than he expected, and my installation will be subject to stresses, so I'd like to substitute it with a better quality shunt.  However, where I'm looking for shunts, I'm finding only 50mV ones.  Eg. http://www.bandc.biz/ammeterloadmetershunts-1.aspx

Will a 20A 50mV DC shunt take the place of this 30A 75mV DC shunt with minimal loss of accuracy?

My understanding is that the 50mV or 75mV is the measurement at full needle deflection, and if 20A creates 50mV, then it scales linearly, so 1A would create 2.5mV, and 30A will create 75mV.  In fact, the gauge even has a cryptic 2.5 mark on the face, I believe to indicate 2.5mV per (1A) mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If 75 mV is developed across a shunt at 30 Amperes, then by Ohms Law the shunt resistance is $$R = \frac{V}{I} = \frac{75 \text{mV}}{30 \text{A}} = 2.5 \text{m}\Omega$$

So if all you can find are 50 mV shunts, then you might think that a shunt of the same resistance as above, with a nominal current of: $$I = \frac{V}{R} = \frac{50 \text{mV}}{2.5 \text{m}\Omega} = 20 \text{A}$$ should do the job.

The problem, of course, is that the 20 Ampere shunt is not guaranteed to survive 30 Amperes running through it.

**Solution:**

Two shunts in series, of 1.25 mOhms each, of the 50 mV variety. For 50 mV rated shunts to be of 1.25 mOhm, the rating you would look for is 40 Amperes, 50 mV.

Two of those in series develop the same 75 mV end to end when 30 Amperes flow through them. Calculate: $$V = 2 \times I \times R = 2 \times 30 \times 1.25 \text{m}\Omega = 75 \text{mV}$$ Perfect.

Best of all, those 40 Ampere rated shunts will comfortably survive a 30 ampere current, so you are home free.

Comment: Well that’s in an ideal world. In the real world the shunts need to be calibrated to determine true value which will change due to current through them and heating.

Comment: That won't work - shunts have Kelvin connections to eliminate the effects of parasitic resistances. You can't connect 2 in series and preserve the Kelvin performance.